# How to get menu item from ptree when leaf = true?

Tags: angular, primeng

please advise...
I have p-tree on my page. When the last element is reached I set leaf=true.
But in this case when I click on it I can't get the value of the node!

```
   <p-tree class="w-full md:w-30rem" [value]="calendarFilterService.treeData" filter]="true" (onNodeContextMenuSelect)="nodeExpand($event)")="nodeExpand($event)"[loading]="loading"></p-tree>
```

How to get menu item content from p-tree when leaf = true ?